# Building "HTML5 PSD files from comps"

Tags: website-design, terminology

I'm applying for a gig and one of the requirements is "Experience building ... HTML5 PSD files from comps". Can someone expand on what is meant by "HTML5 PSD files from comps"?

I understand what HTML5 is and what a PSD is, but I'm not clear on the particular workflow implied here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an error in the requirements which made it confusing. It should say "experience building HTML websites from PSD comps".

This means creating good, modern HTML based on a Photoshop document.

Comment: I'd add that with the specific inclusion of HTML *5* they're probably talking about responsive or adpatable sites, liquid layout, avoiding flash, java-based menu animations and all that jazz.

Comment: Agreed. It's a buzz term though :P It effectively means "modern" web pages